# Weird problem, with ghostscript and pdf files

Tags: pdf, landscape, postscript, ghostscript

am using ghostscript to create pdf file from postscript file. My PS file, doesn't have orientation instructions, so when I want to create landscape pdf file, I'm using ghostscript to rotate the page. The problem is, that ghostscript rotates only the first page, and when my pdf file is more than 1 page, the others, are not rotated correctly. Here is the command I'm using:

```
cat $psinput | gs -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOuputFile="/tmp/pdf" \
        -dAutoRotatePages="/None" -c "<< /Orientation 3 >> setpagedevice" \
        90 rotate 0 -595 translate -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop  -f - -c -quit
```

Does anybody have an idea how to correct this?

Comment: @kofucii: `-dAutoRotatePages="/None"` can be without quotes: `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`. Same for `-sOuputFile=/tmp/pdf`. Not sure if that can cause you grieve or is harmless, though. -- **However, the `-c`-construct most definitely is wrongly placed and wrongly quoted!** It should be at the very end, just before the `-f -` input   data statement, like this: `... -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice 90 rotate 0 -595 translate" -f - -c quit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your actual `$psinput` it is difficult to give definite advice. Your $psinput, coming via stdin to Ghostscript, could contain multiple PS files... Have you tried playing with one of these options

- `-dOrient1=true`
- `-dOrient1=false`

in your commandline? Also, it looks to me like you should put your *90 rotate 0 -595 translate* command inside the quotes going with `-c`, and then position the input (*-f -*) to the very end of processing like so:

- `-c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice 90 rotate 0 -595 translate" -f - -c quit`

Also have you tried to use

- `-c ".setpdfwrite <<//AutoRotatePages /PageByPage>> setdistillerparams"` or
- `-c ".setpdfwrite <<//AutoRotatePages /All>> setdistillerparams"` or
- `-c ".setpdfwrite <<//AutoRotatePages /None>> setdistillerparams"`

on your commandline (with or without your original rotating code)?

Answer (score 0):

If you must not use ghostscript to do the rotation, you can probably use [pdftk](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/) or [impose](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/pdf/Impose.html) instead.